# multi-conditional logic in Java

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment that has been driving me insane, I have tried several different algorithms to solve the problem with no luck.

I made a GUI, the GUI has two text boxes with three buttons below an add, subtract, and clear button. When numbers are entered in the top two boxes, and the add or subtract are pressed the math is performed and the results show up in the result box. The last part of my assignment is to add a check box that when it is checked, and one of the values is over 5000 the result of an add or subtract method call is shown in red in the results box.

I have tried nested 'if' statements but that did not work, my last attempt was to use '&&' to test for two conditions: 'Jcheckbox state changed && num1/num2 >= 5000.'

What can I do differently?

Comment: people are going to want you to post sample code so we can better help instead of making guesses.

Comment: It's hard to imagine what you have already worked on based on what you described, if you show your work people can better help you.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track and that's the logic you should be using. What went wrong? What was the output? I think you are going to have to post code here.

Comment: Sounds like you're having trouble checking the state of a JCheckBox, use the [isSelected()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) method: `if(jcheckbox.isSelected() && (num1 >= 5000 || num2 >= 5000))`  Further, do the same calculations and change the text color to red, or whatever component is supposed to be red.

Comment: I don't want anybody to do my homework, which is why I was trying not to post any code or have anybody post code to solve the problem. I just cant wrap my head around the question, and I don't know why because it looks like a simple problem. I will put up the code shortly, not on my school computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside your add/subtract methods:

```
if the `JCheckBox` is checked
    if num1 or num2 >= 5000
        do the calculation
        put it in the result box
        draw a red border on result box
    else
        draw black border
        do whatever your assignment says
else 
    draw black border
    do the calculation
    put it in the result box
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see why my if statement did not work. I had put it with JCheckbox, and now I see why I should have put my code up initially. It makes much more sense when looking at the code, I was trying to avoid getting specific help.